# HTML Form Signature -> Save to excel

Tags: php, html, forms

I am "developing" an online form for a friend of mine where the truck drivers of his business have to fill in when they drove and where they drove and so on and how they cleaned the truck afterwards.
I had also the task to automatically generate an excel file from the data within the MySQL database.
Everything is up and running but now I have a problem:

Before the online form was created they had to fill in a sheet of paper and they had to sign it.

Now my friend wants to have a field where the drivers can sign it using their finger or a pen.

This wouldn't be a problem because of various jquery plugins but how should I store the signature in the database?
And is it possible to insert the signature into an excel row?
because now every entry is just one row in excel (did it with phpexcel) and as the last cell in this row i would need the signature.

how would you do this?

ps: the friends mom just wants do download the excel file and finish.

Answer (score 0):

Save the image coming from your form to a temporary file.

Create a drawing object using

```
new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
```

Tahir Yasin wrote in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609019/adding-a-logo-to-an-excel-sheet-using-php-excel) how to do it in detail.

To save the image to the db use base64, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-image-to-base64-encoding).